# Haskell Filter Multiples of 3 from a List to a Sublist

Tags: list, haskell, filter, sublist

I am still trying to grasp the way Haskell and Functional Programming works, and I need help understanding why my function is not working. I am trying to create a function that takes a list of integers as a parameter and filters out/returns a sublist which contains any multiples of 3 from the first list. Here is my code:

```
module Main where

sublist = []

myFunc :: [Int] -> [Int]

myFunc [] = []

myFunc [t] = do
    if t `mod` 3 == 0
        then t : sublist
    else myFunc []

myFunc (h:t) = do
    if h `mod` 3 /= 0
        then myFunc t
        else do
            h : sublist
            myFunc t
```

This only returns a list containing the last value passed to the function, and still sublist = []. Thanks for any advice you can give me in advance.

Comment: Your code looks like you don't understand the principles of immutability.  The statement `t : sublist` doesn't change sublist at all, it simply yields a list just containing `t` (`sublist` will always be empty as that's how immutability works - the binding won't change).

Comment: You don't need `do`s here. Don't use `do` until you learn about monads. (Okay, you can probably get away with using `do` notation with `IO` before you use monads, but for nothing else.)

Comment: Working out why this code compiles at all and, once it compiles, why it behaves as it does is a lovely exercise for the mid-level Haskell programmer. =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to first switch over mentally to functional style.

for example, this is to get even numbers from a list

```
> filter even [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

without using the existing functions you can implement the same functionality

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' condition (x:xs) = if condition x
                              then x : filter' condition xs
                              else     filter' condition xs

divisibleBy3 n = mod n 3 == 0
```

now, your program can be written as

```
filter' divisibleBy3 inputList
```

Comment: Thank you, this code was very helpful. Is there a resource that you or somebody else could recommend to help me make the mental switch to functional style? I've tried to grasp recursive functions in Prolog as well and I cannot understand it well enough to effectively solve problems that would be easy for me in a language like C++.

Comment: If you're starting fresh perhaps a book is more useful.  I can recommend Bird's Thinking Functionally in Haskell, but there are many others, perhaps the free option LYAH but I didn't read it.